# HTML <p> tag ignores database line breaks

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am attempting to return complicated text from my database. This text appears in the database with line breaks. They ARE there.

The problem is when I use php to retrieve these elements from the database and `echo` them into a `<p>` tag, the line breaks do not appear. Is there a attribute I am missing?

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "<h1><u>".$row['title']."</u></h1>".$row['date']."<br><br><br>";

echo '<img src="'.$row['image1'].'" />';
if(strlen($row['video'])>0)
{
      echo '<video src="'.$row['video'].'" width="800" height="600" />';
}
if(strlen($row['body'])>0)
      echo '<p >'.$row['body'].'</p>';
if(strlen($row['image2'])>0)
      echo '<img src="'.$row['image2'].'" />';
if(strlen($row['body2'])>0)
      echo '<p>'.$row['body2'].'</p>';
if(strlen($row['code'])>0)
      echo '<p>'.$row['code'].'</p>';
```

Comment: `\n` or `<br>`? One will render in the browser, the other will not

Comment: @JohnConde I figured that much. Is there a work around?

Comment: Scroll the page. `echo '<p> ' . nl2br($row['body'] . '</p>';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<p> ' . nl2br($row['body']) . '</p>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: You can also use `<pre>` tag, if you don't want to call nl2br, and don't care for monospaced (by default) font. It cares for `\n` newlines.

Comment: You should call `nl2br` when saving the content in the database, the content (the text) will directly have the `<br />` when you will display this field.